# Machine readable output of "diff -r"

Tags: directory, diff

Is there any machine readable output for comparing two directories with `diff`?

If I do `diff -rq a b` I get:

```
Only in a: aa
Only in b: bb
Files a/t and b/t differ
```

But maybe something like the following would be easier to interpret in a script:

```
- aa
+ bb
d t
```

Comment: Looks doable with text-processing. Delete "Only in", a`: -> -`, `b: -> +`,  and use only what's after the last / to report the differ line. Of course, maybe not so simple with weird file names with subdirectories... Good luck.

Comment: I use the `--ifdef=NAME` option, which lists the whole file with C-preprocessor control statements for inserts, deletes and changes. At least the output is consistently formatted, and thus easy to post-process (e.g. with awk).

Answer (score 1):

Yes the `diff -rq` output is not post-processable, even by a human in the face of weirdly names files. See for instance:

```
$ ls -lFA 1 2
1:
total 20
-rw-rw-r-- 1 chazelas chazelas 5 Aug 20 10:04  a
-rw-rw-r-- 1 chazelas chazelas 2 Aug 20 10:08 'A and B'
-rw-rw-r-- 1 chazelas chazelas 5 Aug 20 10:04 'a'$'\n''b'$'\n''Only in 1: foo'
lrwxrwxrwx 1 chazelas chazelas 4 Aug 20 10:10  lsock -> sock=
lrwxrwxrwx 1 chazelas chazelas 9 Aug 20 10:04  n -> /dev/null
srwxrwxr-x 1 chazelas chazelas 0 Aug 20 10:05  sock=
lrwxrwxrwx 1 chazelas chazelas 9 Aug 20 10:06  z -> /dev/zero

2:
total 14
-rw-rw-r-- 1 chazelas chazelas  5 Aug 20 10:04  a
-rw-rw-r-- 1 chazelas chazelas  2 Aug 20 10:08 'A and B'
lrwxrwxrwx 1 chazelas chazelas 17 Aug 20 10:09  lsock -> /run/udev/control=
lrwxrwxrwx 1 chazelas chazelas  9 Aug 20 10:05  n -> /dev/zero
lrwxrwxrwx 1 chazelas chazelas  9 Aug 20 10:10  sock -> ../1/sock=
lrwxrwxrwx 1 chazelas chazelas  9 Aug 20 10:05  z -> /dev/zero
```

```
$ diff -rq 1 2
Files 1/A and B and 2/A and B differ
Only in 1: a
b
Only in 1: foo
File 1/lsock is a socket while file 2/lsock is a socket
File 1/n is a character special file while file 2/n is a character special file
```

See for yourself what you can make out of that output.

Here, if it's just about knowing which files are in one and not in the other, and for those that are common to both, decide how you want to compare them based on their type, then it's not two hard to do by hand.

For instance, with `zsh`:

```
zmodload zsh/stat
dirA=some/dir
dirB=some/other/dir
A_files=( $dirA/**/*(NDe['REPLY=${REPLY#$dirA/}']) )
B_files=( $dirB/**/*(NDe['REPLY=${REPLY#$dirB/}']) )

only_in_A=( ${A_files:|B_files} )
only_in_B=( ${B_files:|A_files} )
common_files=( ${A_files:*B_files} )
exact_same=()
different_type=()
different_content_regular=()
for file ($common_files) {
  stat -LsH a -- $dirA/$file && stat -LsH b -- $dirB/$file || continue
  if [[ $a[device]:$a[inode] = $b[device]:$b[inode] ]]; then
    exact_same+=( $file )
  elif [[ ${a[mode][1]} != ${b[mode][1]} ]]; then
    different_type+=( $file )
  elif [[ ${a[mode][1]} = - ]]; then
    (( a[size] == b[size] )) && cmd -s -- $dirA/$file $dirB/$file ||
      different_content_regular+=( $file )
  else
    : decide what to do with other types of files
  fi
}
```

(untested).

Then you end up with a number of arrays for the different types of differences, and can decide on how to compute and handle the differences. For instance, there are many ways you could want to handle symlinks. In the code above if `$dirA/foo` and `$dirB/foo` are the same symlink (they are hard linked together), the above will add them to `$exact_same`, but if they point to `file`, a relative path in their respective directory, then their contents may very well be different.